# Combinatorics - Counting Something Similar to Unsigned Stirling Numbers of the First Kind

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

I want to count something similar to unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind. Can someone tell me what math describes the quantity I'm interested in?

Suppose I have $n$ people numbered $1, 2, ..., n$ and a sequence of $n$ empty sets. I sequentially choose one person at a time, in the ordering of their numbers, and either place that person in any non-empty set in my sequence or in the first empty set in my sequence. For example, if $n=3$, I start with the sequence of 3 empty sets:

{}{}{}

For person $1$, I must place them in the first empty set:

{1}{}{}

For person $2$, I have two choices. I can either add them to the first set or the second set:

{1, 2}{}{}

{1}{2}{}

For person $3$, if I took the first option for person $2$, I now have two choices:

{1, 2, 3}{}{}

{1, 2}{3}{}

And if I took the second option for person $2$, I now have three choices:

{1, 3}{2}{}

{1}{2, 3}{}

{1}{2}{3}

I'm interested in counting the number of ways that the last person $n$ can end up in each set. In this example, there are 2 ways for person $3$ to end up in the first set, 2 ways to end up in the second set, and 1 way to end up in the third set. What combinatoric function describes the number of ways that the last person $n$ can end up in each set?

Comment: Computing some values we could suppose they are [Bell numbers](https://oeis.org/A000110).

Comment: @BillyJoe: No, the Bell numbers give the total number of outcomes for a given $n$; what’s wanted here is the number $a(n,k)$ of outcomes for a given $n$ that have $n$ in the $k$-th set. If I’m not mistaken, $a(1,1)=1$; $a(2,1)=a(2,2)=1$; $a(3,1)=a(3,2)=2$ and $a(3,3)=1$; and $a(4,1)=a(4,2)=5$, $a(4,3)=4$, and $a(4,4)=1$.

Comment: Have a look at this grid https://oeis.org/A133611

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for item $n$ to end up in set $k$, the first $n-1$ items need to span at least $k-1$ sets. The number of ways $n-1$ objects can span exactly $i$ sets is the Stirling number ${n-1 \brace i }$. Therefore, the number of ways to have item $n$ in spot $k$ is
$$
{n-1 \brace k-1} + {n-1 \brace k} + \dots + {n-1 \brace n-1}
$$